# how to increase size of character so as not to truncate the imported field

Tags: r

Input data is of format A=integer, B=text [word count max 500]

Importing this data set into R truncates the second column to fit chr.  Is there a different class that will ensure no truncation or a method to increase the size of chr to accommodate the entire text? (conceptually equivalent to a TEXT vs VARCHAR in sql)

```
xdoc <- read.csv("./data/abtest2.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",", as.is = TRUE)
```

> head(xdoc)
>   A 1 601004351600
>
> B 1
>   adsfj al;ds fj;sd jf;klsdj f dsfdfsdf sdf sdf sdf as a dag dfgh tyutr
>   erigkdj fajklsdf j;sdkl ;klajdfsiljuaeiodgjdfl;gdASo ri[3iocvjilgjdfi
>   gjksjfl jgeoutoihjkvhlkasj;aljdsgkjdfghkdm,gfn;lkja;ja;drfjgkihyuirhl
>   jkjfdkl hjgasdhgdfjkgksdjkj r...

Comment: you haven't given us a reproducible example, nor enough clues to figure out what might be going on.  This is not expected behavior from R ...

Comment: Perhaps, Any spurious  line breaks in the input data?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's something about the way in which you're *viewing* the files.

```
longwords <- replicate(10,paste(
        sample(letters,600,replace=TRUE),collapse=""))
nchar(longwords)  ## 600 600 600 600 ...
dd <- data.frame(n=1:10,w=longwords)
write.csv(dd,file="tmp.csv",row.names=FALSE)
```

Now read the data file back in -- it's the same as when it was written out

```
xdoc <- read.csv("tmp.csv",as.is=TRUE)
nchar(xdoc$w)
## [1] 600 600 600 600 600 ...
```

I don't know what kind of limits there are on string length in R other than memory size, but they're long.  Perhaps this note from `?as.character` is relevant ... ?

```
> ‘as.character’ breaks lines in language objects at 500 characters,
 and inserts newlines.  Prior to 2.15.0 lines were truncated.
```

So something else, either in your viewing procedure or in the way you've processed the data, is messing you up.

```
head(xdoc)
  n
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 6
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         w
1 llscwhauaiqfqcftzfqujwqefathrchnneqwkcoktrpnebpylyjkoiqyscegbmdwmiegivulxnqxjlrcjiwrsfbltdrcymcmpeolxpexxcjhrggqjuphahysgocgjtsafueqzrnvcsofeuxfworytsnfrclsxozrmoitlpfunvmoomgijudjrjngynbrpfotbxzktjbctyafofvyjeegwuiavxrzhropgdtkbwsszwetxcgrrsymcjwstrmrqkaqlwuccikpbtjjwssvxvrrldzfjdqtythlhhzslxvhxrojskaxxuhcnmqppbymxvmqzbyhtzqfgljelvcmsmwsdbytqkvhkgyhreomxohpjtcbiffeuqgwrolwqgmmxevifadnqkxgbentgxazfspzztpuulvpqrbioelzhimyxzhrmdltlmynfpkaqldvwhaicmykjmlxmffrqlukqiwdmhrwygkricdozrggopnsknwduqxrmzovnrzcumddwtqzipfwmdijqgnclenqemecguxqfvbfyxcwpswmzrcvnuqohruphgkzljxgovddliiwdsrfobimtcboljtkxcmzfqwi
2 xuevtjfterzujzmauuvbwkszsbvcmyllddxnebwxgbwnqzlxhsppyxfnynjqkbzzuypxqaselnvwciusswranngvzmxgoxpjuawyaxxgtuisnifdcuqukluqlpwaqznbvlgltryvliwpqwmzrssadzocbiputgsyvfatwdhrbpjnhawdfqcssfkpqimyebfihcmkphsaybnyukzdjlggbkmjkogszslcossstvcehuyunrqapaggmvosouccuzpwjcyyqyizkyzqbcbsnsuewjkeicclfbxhlmishlxggnpluoovhlhcvxqqebzihrhtwjsbvrstddpqqpevjxvmprgthqkdiqgzbzvxjthnjuxvmbpijyvnxuwgemztexcpvouuasdikegxfiqdscjsgpjuvkxeweelfrvfuhllswebmxktpofxusqaqzdrbrybytufvuavknulcnikckayqhoxxsbjhwxcidtpxiwjwqpecmseutimbkfyjfbslhbvdrquefmeqggtbfogjoozbrcfsucxokbdvinnuoolriszkrgbeplswmrujgejsolidvyrdutqnejgrlkeoqqpguks
3 ohhbcsacskcpfjptbbvddwuzwbguedjqyowktvrinuzifawboyqgomhqrxahkbbuoyvsfbwwqstreomtzmdlszdndeurvehobdkzzqffxqgpgkcnqbwrrdcewlfbouveqpbwruoqnmbbodjbhetantlffwzpiefnwreimkoxjwswhdpncqgyvaulwehcuyyngidtdpscxysjqcydwbrqvhpjejudsondgltrrmmydrlnbqjaamdfnivundbupuaialqhuvivfiwtzmdahrtsgvaooardpdiwcinxzvrjrfufmjpsmtugrzqfibdyzgznahftzhlraqubtgnbbrrlursixsgzggbxqrjaqpzgmekqrtyawavhbmlcfcluhvwxfwcvjmxmlwkkzsleayftbxiufysupsygpoklqckxcwfpscleyidikrqvudpjzsqebwodmjkndzagemlofmznaoamedremdtrtbvrqmncxcjoydarnqfukqrapgcewncmhrdmpehiosurelobpqxhfiqksimmvcllcsdnefsvkpcwpokzgnpyluvescbztdlsnyduaxnjlrqgtpgkhclexnbd
4 njpjvhthxdkwrhjvzgnjmceketvjoxeaorxyasibcdhgallwbtvdixviamkrjgrgrwmnkxnihclcuxwoyitwnstlfpqqdwaqtilbmihzshpreexixbrqqhzblmkiptpieqhptczxocchzhbdweualevdoqdzbjdcxlosbgvexcbgwopmrvlqoquknwgcoulqdpmvnlsaxchtqxzzdqnnxukbrfvlfyhssidxsmyqkwmghzdkleccscagvkdioydhjyihgesczherzyoiolgmgyefriokqrxvhbpbzszugnogafoonprykardrjhuqrtdacydaefhrhrgvelehknavjuspgvulgaixgfjrgnmzsagbrxekwwegidduogyxohrfsvcahohggbhabwzkgxpqqrabwnkdeprfkrzlqvqwlqocfohhokxgjjvixvszkdhvszunsdqzzcgezdgvluholijbuitornmpjvggkqsqxhlnxsbujtjpriksthpmfqvhcnhvrnxxpjfrrulzjnfbmlemtvlemhtwfzdypabgcljgegdiehklzfgocsfbfmammpceocxddwpqlrmcvjbldkx
5 hawfcjfxgucbgcjggkfplsgcsncipmjnrwatlhwkrjokunomffyvmrvdkenbwahirvimlauvtefealzgkxihtfitevmffqtizbkvdidmgyshuvvwugpddwxxijtexrlnelbhftpczkxlwecmzxwpzfmaosixyzejbgandcuuiknattwgnopcrpfdhgdxdgnvumacvhnwgvlwmplnjroenogsjlrqroivbvibicxprylsoamxmhcumsbdqhvhwsmizemfnvxvlpbrhdqjyotgteomiymxqsyvcimxyxdyiplmohjnoxamibvselbbujdfnvwmycggsvqmhdrcwddpmqlgtuujqaadtinfuwiyghofqkxbgqdqqvqknhfehxhnamlwvingtaqdwmtgvsxplthzhlzolsjlwuvnxrzioxjvxlwcyssfrxljmikbqjfhevynsetwysnevxsczqbekfrpbbomvpphewrhprpabefhssuooubmxjhksqkljgglkewjkxafrorjuwlwjxyvioywztmaaruyekwuwlajfybievzchqviuueoaxosoeglxgbvlrehhnrmgmljruvygkvp
6 wirtvzltqsseidfrlezfrmaakmroyeztniyoiwwumqhuzqehlymaumrxqupxsfxmgmvoesvcgnavlamsqxbnzhesqsdsjajpowlevkwpifqlyinnifvsmyymrpfbmobrealrommitauwzxzkoohoppqwhfgfyqkdienrejptrvmaaoxwvdkmxeddfzynbiayrpfvrayjuvvcekbnfjtqyohyvkivoggovrodqyqxzbzyplmisqcreigwbjvabwoyfjfkgxssnafhicpercfievxgbbgpbqvfeeduletbmanmfckimsbeegeqrtfdmsqftqtmfwkfnjikxzipsjpbjcjncssmajqisellewvhunzgnmncplslsiuqngxecktxwzuyvwvlhdolkoarzcemluebjcvxckolwyebtxodqsbaleppqdluinwlafciqbfgfawcpsgocliyzeqxlkcwvptgicrtuffqdypeqojtfooaapvstolguhdgrwinzwxiglsxenkeghjdpitkxowqdtmekbqfpvtfrhpmebnrkvwdytzrzuigzyesyhssdaoircggxozljfrtoylsmnkkvfxk
>
```

Comment: Thank you. But, I was unable to figure out the issue.